# Flutter - 'package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/_image_provider_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 20 pos 16: 'url != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

CachedNetworkImageProvider requires a non-Null URL to be passed. 
what i am trying to do is: When _singleCategoryImage is null, just color the box as default else show the image but can't really figure out of to do it.

I'm getting this error.

```
'package:cached_network_image/src/image_provider/_image_provider_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 20 pos 16: 'url != null': is not true.
```

Source:

```
Widget singleCategoryTemp(_singleCategoryText, _singleCategoryImage) {
  return Card(
      elevation: 0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return Container(
              margin: (EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 27)),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  _singleCategoryText,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 17),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              decoration:
              new BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(_singleCategoryImage),
                 /* image: NetworkImage(
                      _singleCategoryImage), */
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                // gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.purple]),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                color: Color(0xFF6d6e70)
              ),
            );
          }));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a ternary operator to evaluate if using the image or not

```
decoration: _singleCategoryImage != null
  ? new BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(_singleCategoryImage),
        /* image: NetworkImage(
        _singleCategoryImage), */
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      // gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.purple]),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      color: Color(0xFF6d6e70))
  : new BoxDecoration(....), //<==== Your decoration without image
```

Or maybe this other option to just avoid loading the image but using the same `BoxDecoration`

```
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: _singleCategoryImage != null
          ? DecorationImage(
              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(_singleCategoryImage),
              /* image: NetworkImage(
_singleCategoryImage), */
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
          : null,
      // gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.purple]),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      color: Color(0xFF6d6e70)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that, The URL you are providing to load image from network is null, try to check the url with print statement.